# Should I wait on command when using StdoutPipe when using exec.Command?

Tags: go, stream, pipe, exec

I'm building a small audio application for personal use and need to pipe to some external tools.

I want to structure my program around `io.ReadCloser`s that I transform and pipe in to PulseAudios `paplay` command.

A simplified example:

```golang
package main

import (
  "os/exec"
)

func main () {
  speech, err := Say("Hello world!")
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  err = Play(speech)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
}

// Say creates a stream containing text as a text-to-speech wav audio stream.
func Say(text string) (io.ReadCloser, error) {
  speak := exec.Command("espeak", "--stdout", text)

  out, err := speak.StdoutPipe()
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }

  return out, speak.Start()
}

// Play a wav audio stream.
func Play(s io.ReadCloser) error {
  play := exec.Command("paplay")

  play.Stdin = s
  play.Stderr = os.Stderr

  return play.Run()
}
```

This is a simplified example, but I'd like to create wav streams using different commands, concatenate them and pipe them to `paplay`.

The go docs on [`exec.Cmd`](https://godoc.org/os/exec#Cmd.Wait) specify that I need to call `Wait` on each command to ensure the resources allocated for running the command are cleared:

> Wait releases any resources associated with the Cmd.

But at the same time it is unclear if I need to call this when using [`StdoutPipe`](https://godoc.org/os/exec#Cmd.StdoutPipe).

Will go clean up the command after the stdout pipe is exhausted and the command has exited or do I need to rethink my abstractions here?

Answer (score 1):

> But at the same time it is unclear if I need to call this when using StdoutPipe.

Yes you still need to `Wait()` to consider cmd instances ended completely.

However, to pipe the stdout stream, its close signal suffices to detect the end of copy.

The doc says

> StdoutPipe returns a pipe that will be connected to the command's
>   standard output when the command starts.
>
> **Wait will close the pipe after seeing the command exit**, so most
>   callers need not close the pipe themselves; however, an implication is
>   that it is incorrect to call Wait before all reads from the pipe have
>   completed. For the same reason, it is incorrect to call Run when using
>   StdoutPipe. See the example for idiomatic usage.

---

> Will go clean up the command after the stdout pipe is exhausted and the command has exited or

yes.

> do I need to rethink my abstractions here?

no.

your code is ok.